# Redmine wiki help button is not working

Tags: redmine

Button Help (?), which should show wiki syntax help, shows "Page not found" and opens strange url (%entities are really there)

```
http://redmine.bisnode.cz/projects/org-redmine-redmine/wiki/Wiki/Form%C3%A1tov%C3%A1n%C3%AD%20textu:%20%3Ca%20href=%22/help/wiki_syntax.html%22%20class=%22help-link%22%20onclick=%22window.open("/help/wiki_syntax.html",%20"",%20"resizable=yes,%20location=no,%20width=300,%20height=640,%20menubar=no,%20status=no,%20scrollbars=yes");%20return%20false;%22%3EN%C3%A1pov%C4%9Bda%3C/a%3E%20&%20%3Ca%20href=%22/plugin_assets/wiking/help/wiki_syntax.html%22%20class=%22help-link%22%20onclick=%22window.open("/plugin_assets/wiking/help/wiki_syntax.html",%20"",%20"resizable=yes,%20location=no,%20width=300,%20height=640,%20menubar=no,%20status=no,%20scrollbars=yes");%20return%20false;%22%3EV%C3%ADce%3C/a%3E
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what problem was - WikiNG plugin. Updating plugin to newest version (from svn) fixed the problem.

Comment: I did update Wiking plugin to the latest, bu the problem is still not resolved :( Using redmine 2.5

Answer (score 0):

In Redmine Redmine 3.3.0.stable.1233 it appeared to me.

I solved it by applying this patch:

```
Index: lib/wiking_wiki_helper_patch.rb
===================================================================
--- lib/wiking_wiki_helper_patch.rb (revision 78)
+++ lib/wiking_wiki_helper_patch.rb (working copy)
@@ -49,10 +49,10 @@

             if defined? ChiliProject
                 url = url_for(:controller => 'help', :action => 'wiki_syntax')
-            elsif File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/help', current_language.to_s.downcase, 'wiki_syntax.html'))
-                url = "#{Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root}/help/#{current_language.to_s.downcase}/wiki_syntax.html"
+            elsif File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/help', current_language.to_s.downcase, 'wiki_syntax_textile.html'))
+                url = "#{Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root}/help/#{current_language.to_s.downcase}/wiki_syntax_textile.html"
             else
-                url = "#{Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root}/help/wiki_syntax.html"
+                url = "#{Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root}/help/wiki_syntax_textile.html"
             end

             if File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, 'plugins/wiking/assets/help/', current_language.to_s.downcase, 'wiki_syntax.html'))
```

Found at: http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/issues/2403

Best regards.